# Can't connect to vpn website

Tags: google-chrome

I can't connect to my companies website anymore on google chrome on my home computer. I tested it on a live cd with success, so I assumed I did something to the OS that made it incompatible somehow. I did a complete reinstall, and it still doesn't work. I also tested google chrome on the libraries computers with success, so it has to be that I did something at home, probably a setting. I can see it on firefox on my installed OS but not google chrome:

[image: Company_Website]

But on google chrome I get this error message:

[image: Error]

Now I am getting a new error message, I haven't seen this one before, but here it is:

[image: Error_1]

I also hit CTRL+ALT+T before going to the site. I got no additional information:

[image: Terminal]
Not sure what to do about this one. This is important because it's how I get my schedule for work. Thank you all in advance for your kind support.

Comment: When I try to put the key part of the URL to my web browser, it redirects to the domain secureweb.kroger.com. Hasn’t something changed in your company? What were you trying to achieve with CTRL+ALT+T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro, The website is blocked by your network Admin.

Comment: i wonder if the word spankin' has triggered some kind of porn filter and the OP's account has been limited.  Either way you are right they need to talk to the local admin.

Comment: I just don't understand why it is blocked on google chrome but not firefox. That makes me think it's something on my side. I did check with corporate and my HR manager, they tend to agree.

Comment: I just tested it on google chrome at the library with success, so it isn't google chrome, it has to be something else entirely on my home operating system.

Comment: I got it working. I guess a little patience was in order. Other than that I can't think what I did differently. I waited about 5 seconds and it worked. At any rate, I will vote your answer anyway.  I am just happy that it's working now.